# No static method hasOnClickListeners found after changing Support.v7

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-appcompat

I've got an odd issue with a Activity I've just tried to convert to a MvxAppCompatActivity (MvvmCross 4).  The error I'm getting is

> Message:
>   No static method hasOnClickListeners(Landroid/view/View;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/XXXX-1/base.apk)
>
> Stack Trace:
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms)
>   Android.Views.LayoutInflater+IFactory2Invoker.OnCreateView(Android.Views.View parent, System.String name, Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxLayoutInflater+DelegateFactory2.OnCreateView(Android.Views.View parent, System.String name, Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Binders.MvxLayoutInflaterCompat+FactoryWrapper2.OnCreateView(Android.Views.View parent, System.String name, Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)

I've spent a few hours trying to convert some existing Activities to use MvxAppCompatActivity, after a lot of experimenting this seems to only happen once I add a TextView I don't know what other Views are problematic, Linear, Relative etc seem ok.   I've made a test solution which seems to be ok but that doesn't really help me with my existing solution.  I can't spot any differences in the setup (Android version targeted, NuGet packages etc).  There is just a lot more code in the problem solution.

Is there anything I should be looking at here?  I wasn't using any V7.AppCompat functionality before so I may have introduced something. I had some custom bindings but I've removed them for now.

Android Settings:
[image: Android Settings]

Comment: What compiler level are you using?

Comment: Added Android settings to question

Comment: Have you tried removing all the packages clean your project then add them again?

Comment: So having an xml folder in resources with anything in it causes an error in completely unrelated layouts. Still don't know what caused the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cheesebaron was right in the end removing all the AppCompat packages, cleaning and re-installing them solved the problem.  I had some how lost the reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.V4.

However I couldn't see that solution as another problem appeared. I had an xml folder with preferences in.  This causes another error which I've checked happens with a standard AppCompatActivity. No idea why but it does, can be proved by downloading: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar add a resources/xml folder and any xml file and you get an error or at least I did.